# How do I add quotes in a string concatenation operation in Python?

Tags: python

If on the python shell we put:

```
name='stackof'

name+'runs'
```

Shouldn't it give

```
'stackof''runs'
```

But it gives

```
'stackofruns'
```

Comment: No it shouldn't, and I'm not clear on why you think it should.

Comment: this line `name+'runs'` join string to each other, why do you need : `'stackof''runs'`

Comment: it wont, you could instead store it with concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

No it actually appends both the strings. For the behaviour you want you have to write like this

```
name="'stackof'"
```

then

```
name + "'runs'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result that you want if you do the following:

```
>>>name = "stackof"
>>>name + "''" + "runs"
>>>"stackof''runs"
```

Even when you assign "runs" to another variable and concatenate the two, it would result 'stackofruns'.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "'stackof'"

print(name+"'runs'")
```

Answer (score 0):

A string represents character sequences within quotes, either single quotes ' ' or double quotes " ".

For the string `name = 'stackof'` the actual contents are `stackof`, the quotes are not included.

So when `name+'runs'` is executed the contents inside the quotes i.e `stackof` and `runs` are taken and the result is stored inside a new string as `'stackofruns'`